# Omitting the existential "there" and the dummy "it" in sentences

Tags: grammaticality

Steve Glassman in the book "On the Trail of the Maya Explorer" writes:

> *On the walls were pictures*, some drawn by artists of Guatemala and
>   others that had been brought from Spain.

Is [it] consistent with the grammar rules omitting the existential "there" there—e.g., "On the walls ***there*** were pictures, [...]"? If not, why not?

Instead, if so, can I omit the dummy "it" in "Is ***it*** consistent with [...]"?

Or are the two cases different and, so, they should be treated differently?

Comment: "On the walls there were pictures" sounds awkward. It should either be "There were pictures on the walls" or "On the walls were pictures". This isn't really a case of dropping an existential "there", but of switching voices from more passive to less passive. Sort of. (I'm not totally sure of my terminology, hence comment not answer.)

Comment: As with Martha, I'm not sure of the terminology to use, but the second case is not correct. "It" is a pronoun referring to something else, and omitting it (ha ha) would leave the sentence without a noun. (Compare "Is *the process* consistent with XYZ?" to "Is consistent with XYZ?")

Answer (score 2):

> **On the walls were pictures, &c** ...

This is an ordinary inversion of *Pictures were on the walls*, expressed this way to focus on the pictures, and place them where they marry most easily with the following description. The verb comes in its usual second place.

> **On the walls [there] were pictures, &c*** ...

In this case, the *there* can be dropped or not, as you prefer, because the syntactic role it is called to play is already occupied. Note that the sentence *There were pictures on the wall* is **already inverted**. Existential *there* is not a pronoun, and is not the subject of this sentence; it is, rather, an adverb acting as ‘dummy’ complement, for the ‘base’ sentence, before inversion, is *Pictures were there*. When you flip the phrase *on the wall* into that position, the *there* becomes superfluous.

> **Is it consistent with grammar rules to omit the existential *there*?**

This is a different sort of inversion—a question, which requires the verb (or its first component) in the first place and the subject in the second. *It*, although it is only a ‘dummy’ pronoun, cannot be omitted because it is the subject of the clause:

> **It is consistent with grammar rules, &c**

If you want to omit the *it* here you must undo the cleft construction which elicits the ‘dummy’ pronoun, then transform that into a question:

> **Omitting the existential *there* is consistent with grammar rules.** >>>
>   **Is omitting the existential *there* consistent with grammar rules?**

You have to have a subject.